# Синтаксический разбор: "Заканчивалась записка просьбой известить её"

Tags: синтаксический-разбор

> *Заканчивалась записка просьбой известить её.*

Если правильно делаю, получается так:

*Записка* (что?) - субъект

*Заканчивалась* (что делает?) - предикат

*просьбой* (чем заканчивалась?) - объект

*известить* (просьбой о чем?/просьбой что сделать?)

*её* (известить кого?)

Скажите, пожалуйста, какую функцию в предложении имеет инфинитив "*известить*"?

Comment: Я бы сформулировал так: "Если я правильно рассуждаю,  получается так..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Заканчивалась записка просьбой (какой?) **известить её**.

Это оборот на основе инфинитива  **в роли несогласованного определения.** В этом предложении оборот не обособляется.

Но такой оборот может обособляться тире: Заканчивалась записка **единственной просьбой (какой именно?) ― известить её.**

В этом случае существительное имеет согласованное определение ***единственной*** с неопределенным значением, которое нуждается в пояснении.

**Розенталь:** http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=110#pp110

3. Несогласованное определение, выраженное неопределенной формой глагола (инфинитивом), перед которой можно поставить слова а именно, отделяется посредством тире: …Я шёл к вам с чистыми побуждениями, **с единственным желанием — сделать добро!**

Comment: Является ли просьба объектом? Разве действие на нее  направлено?

Comment: Под объектом подразумевается дополнение. Заканчивалась записка (чем?) просьбой.

Comment: Тут, кажется, страдательный оборот (подлежащее обозначает лицо или предмет, который подвергается действию, а дополнение - действующее лицо или предмет). Просьба - объект, а записка - субъект. Не так ли?

Comment: Я не вижу здесь страдательного оборота. Дается обычный разбор предложения: подлежащее (субъект), сказуемое, дополнение (объект).

Comment: Разве не просьба заканчивала записку? Пример страдательного оборота у Валгиной: *И яблоня на диком минном поле не будет этим днем обойдена (Прок.).*

Comment: Я думаю. что у нас возвратный залог. Нельзя сказать: Просьба заканчивает записку.